# Set current item on View Pager 2

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs, android-viewpager2

I use View Pager 2 with TabLayout. I have many tabs. And I want to select a tab already created and selected.

[image]

*Here when creating I am using setCurrentItem()*

```
view_pager.setCurrentItem(mMonthsAdapter.itemCount - 1, false)
```

After that I have one action and then I also use setCurrentItem(). But it doesn't work this time. selects the last item and displays the first item. That is, the view pager does not work when I want to show the selected item.

Comment: `view_pager.post {
  view_pager.setCurrentItem(mMonthsAdapter.itemCount - 1, false)
}`

Comment: `new Handler().postDelayed(
                new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      
                            tabLayoutOBJ.getTabAt(mMonthsAdapter.itemCount - 1).select();
                        }
                    }
                }, 100);`

Answer (score 1):

Initially i was skeptic too, but it seems giving a delay is making it work

```
 viewPager.postDelayed({ viewPager.currentItem = mMonthsAdapter.itemCount - 1 }, 100)
```

Try this out